# How to resolve stream_socket_client() in production server

Tags: php, laravel, smtp

I've been having trouble with this, I tried using other mailers but it didn't work, I always get this error when I try to submit

> Connection could not be established with host mail.mydomain.com
> :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
> tcp://mail.mydomain.com:465 (A connection attempt failed because the
> connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
> established connection failed because connected host has failed to
> respond.
> )

Here is my env file

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp 
MAIL_HOST=mail.mydomain.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=test@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=test@mydomain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="test"
```

This works when I'm using xampp (locally), I don't know why it didn't work on our production server.

Comment: Maybe try using port 587 or 25 or 2525

Comment: I tried using port 587 and it worked! I guess the port 465 is block.